Is the product of cocomplete categories cocomplete?
$\def\C{\mathcal{C}}
\def\Hom{\operatorname{Hom}}$That is pretty much the question. Let $\Lambda$ be a set. If $\C_\nu$, $\nu\in\Lambda$, are cocomplete categories, then is $\prod_{\nu\in\Lambda}\C_\nu$ also cocomplete?

Did you actually try to prove this before asking?

$\def\C{\mathcal{C}}
\def\Hom{\operatorname{Hom}}
\def\colim{\operatorname{colim}}$The answer is yes. More specifically, let $I$ be a small category. Then if $\C_\nu$ admits all $I$-shaped colimits for all $\nu\in\Lambda$, then so does $\prod_\nu\C_\nu$. Let $(\alpha_\nu):I\to\prod_\nu\C$ be a diagram. Then for a test element $(T_\nu)\in\prod_\nu\C_\nu$,
\begin{align*}
\lim\Hom_{\prod_\nu\C_\nu}\left((\alpha_\nu),(T_\nu)\right)
&=\lim\prod_\nu\Hom_{\C_\nu}(\alpha_\nu,T_\nu)\\
&\cong\prod_\nu\lim\Hom_{\C_\nu}(\alpha_\nu,T_\nu)
&\text{since limits commute with limits}\\
&\cong\prod_\nu\Hom_{\C_\nu}(\colim\alpha_\nu,T_\nu)\\
&=\Hom_{\prod_\nu\C_\nu}((\colim\alpha_\nu),(T_\nu)).
\end{align*}
This isomorphism in natural in $(T_\nu)$ and thus exhibits $(\colim\alpha_\nu)\in\prod_\nu\C_\nu$ as the colimit of $(\alpha_\nu)$, i.e., $\colim(\alpha_\nu)=(\colim\alpha_\nu)$.
